# Windows IoT Rpi3 CPU temperature indication

Tags: pi-3, windows-iot, temperature

I'm developing a product with Windows 10 IoT Core on Pi3 and would like to monitor the CPU temperature and speed. I know it's possible when running under Linux, but has anyone done it with Windows IoT?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a Python script to read the CPU usage, temperature, and etc.

[How to create python project in windows iot](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/samples/helloworldpython)

---

For install lib (use `pip`):

```
pip install python-psutil
```

And

```
import psutil
psutil.cpu_percent()
```

[image]

I tested it on Linux, but also it works on Windows IOT.

Comment: It does not appear to support reading temperature.

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf
[page 65]

Comment: I'm not sure the SD card controller has any relevance to using psutil to read temperature.